# Installing Windows 10 Dual Boot AFTER installing Ubuntu, on a custom Ubuntu computer

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, usb, windows

I've spent the better part of the entire day trying to install a dual boot of Windows 10 next to my Ubuntu Installation.

I've searched just about every solution to my particular problems which I will get to in a moment, but I believe that it is important that I mention what kind of laptop I have.

I have the Dell XPS13 9370 Developer Edition.
The Developer Edition of the XPS13 shipped with Ubuntu stock, and it also a team of engineers that work on a proprietary PPA specifically for this laptop.
So that means that a factory restore will install ubuntu by default, and in order for me to have the correct PPA already installed by default (although it would be kind of trivial to add them after the fact), AND the factory restore option in the grub menu, I have to install ubuntu first. Definitely wanted to leave factory restore in grub. So, that means that I have to install windows AFTER installing ubuntu. So that's why I had so many issues with this.
But the experience with the stock laptop has been nice, it has been butter smooth, and is literally an out of the box Linux experience. Very satisfied.
I've only accidentally soft bricked it a few times.
I also mentioned the dell/ubuntu situation because I can't just go and download the dell specific windows image for this laptop either, but I might ask dell for that image.

Anyways, so here is what I have done when attempting what should be a pretty straightforward install:

- Ubuntu factory reset.
- I then installed Gparted onto a USB boot drive, and I partitioned my hard drive with 70 gigs of space for windows (I gave the partition an NTFS file system).
- I then made a bootable USB drive with an Ubuntu image. (I've done this with unetbootin, tuxboot, multisystem, and just plain old disks).
- Seemed to be all smooth, but then I tried to boot from USB and install Windows. Each, and every single time, it gives me a "missing media drivers" error.

Now that last part is where I am stuck. I have literally downloaded what I believed to be every Intel driver (including all of the RST drivers that seemed to solve the problem for some people).

I have downloaded every dell driver for this laptop.

I have put all of those drivers onto the usb drive itself, the random partition I made, and an sd card. In all cases, none of them work.

I then did some fudging around with the bios, and tried alternating between the AHCI, None, and RAID options.
I have tried installing literally every driver that was made available from that menu, and they have all given me a "not compatible" message, and I have always had to unclick the "hide drivers not compatible with this machine" radio checkbox.

The only option that made a difference, was the RAID option, where the windows boot sequence seemed to have detected a compatible driver, which was the IASTORAC driver.

Of course, it said that the driver was not up to date, and that I needed to contact my manufacturer.

I then tried every other weird trick that I could find such as loading from one USB port, and then switching to another before activating the install sequence. Again, no luck.

So the only things I haven't tried are:

- Get a new USB stick.
- Ask dell to give me their specific windows image.
- format my usb stick to ntfs, re-install image, and then try again (but I am in the process of this literally as we speak).

Dell will probably not give me the image even if I mention that I have a legitimate product key, as they seemed to be extremely strict and always pointed me to a "help center" where I enter my service tag number to proceed. Their overall service on this laptop has been amazing though, and it's nice to know that they are willing to support linux on one of their flagship machines.

Anyways, does anyone have a clue as to how else I can proceed?
I can't be the only person with this laptop that has tried this, and I'm sure that at least one person has succeeded at it.

Comment: Windows is neither Ubuntu, nor official flavor of Ubuntu thus off-topic on this site.  We are not a dell support site, but a Ubuntu & official flavor of Ubuntu user support site, where you appear to be having issues with specific hardware & an OS (windows 10) neither of which we support.  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I've seen many dual booting questions on this particular site, and I believe it to be relevant to Ubuntu users who want to dual boot windows alongside their stock Ubuntu install.
 If you believe that to be incorrect, and you are a mod, then I guess you can delete it or I can delete it myself and put it on another forum, but I have seen this question, and have also found some clues on this particular stack exchange.
If there's a more specific stack exchange i'll gladly put it there, but as an Ubuntu user that had this problem and couldn't find solutions, I think that it is relevant.

Comment: If you 'solved' it, please add your solution in the 'answer' section. In time you'll be able to accept your own answer

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put the answer (solution) inside your question.

Answer (score 1):

**[Solution] (Repeated here so it can be marked as answered)** 
Geeze, I finally solved it. Sometimes it's just that right combination of things that takes you all day (particularly with drivers and compatability). At least you always learn something everytime you do it. Anyways, here are the exact steps and I hope that no one else has to go through this again lol.

What you will need: USB stick (and dongle if you only have thunderbolt ports). Note: I'm also running Ubuntu 16.04 (which will later be upgraded in place).

- First, you will need to create an NTFS partition on your hard drive. You can't do this on the partition that you're running Ubuntu on while you're running it (But you will be changing that partition after this step). So you will need to download the GParted live CD/USB image and burn it onto a USB. 
  Here's the link : https://gparted.org/livecd.php 
  I used tuxboot to burn the image which can be found here: https://tuxboot.org/ 
  I initially formatted and changed the filesystem of my USB stick to FAT32, and that ran GParted and booted up correctly.
- Next, you will boot GParted (F12 at boot screen and select boot from USB), and create a partition on your hard drive. This can be done by simply using the slider after selecting "Move/Resize" on the partition of your hard drive that Ubuntu is currently installed on (don't mess with swap partitions and other stuff). Resize to something above the min needed for windows and however big you want the partition to be.
  The partition will be unallocated, so you will need to give that block of memory a file system, and it will need to be NTFS. That can also be done in GParted.
- Next, format your USB drive (Using GParted) and give it a filesystem of NTFS.
  Once again, you can log back into Ubuntu to do this (use GParted in Ubunutu not on the USB). Burn your Windows ISO onto your now NTFS Formatted USB drive using Tuxboot.
  If you can't mount your drive now, you may need to install an ntfs package for your Ubuntu installation. `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`
- Once your Windows image is burned onto your USB drive, reboot your system and boot from USB (F12 at startup screen).

That's it! I'm now dual booting.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** You will not have grub (startup menu that let's you select your OS) after doing this, you will have to install it manually. It will boot Windows by default, and you will need to f12 at start to use Ubuntu if you don't install grub. You don't have to drop to terminal or use an Ubuntu Live CD/USB to install it though, you can simply log into your ubuntu partition by pressing f12 and selecting it through the boot menu. Then, install grub, restart, and you should have a select screen (grub menu) everytime you boot up.

Known Bugs (Will add as more surface):
 - If you restart from windows without powering down and you select Ubuntu from the grub menu, Ubuntu will not boot. It will just drop to initramfs terminal.
To Load Ubuntu, you will need to power down your PC completely if you exit of out windows and restart to grub.
Not sure why this is happening, but it might have something to do with the separate file systems of the partitions, and the BIOS adjusting itself to said partitions. I ran disk checks on both partitions (fsck through gparted) and it was clear.